# How to install different versions of the same hybrid application in Windows 8.1?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows 8.1 hybrid mobile app and I need to install (for development purposes) in the device X versions of the same app because it is loading data from different lines, (development, testing or production), How to do this?

Any hint?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the store only installs the latest version. Unlike NuGet you can't get older versions.

Comment: @inane you may try with different identifier names for each environment (development, testing or production) of the same app

Comment: I am modifying "display name in application" and "package name in  packaging" inside of package.windows.appxmanifest, also I have modified config.xml modifying name and widget.id unsuccessfull.. any hint or additional info??